# Looking for server monitoring tool for apache thrift

Tags: rpc, soa, thrift, newrelic, tcpserver

We use new relic for our http based web servers. I was looking for a similar tool for thrift based servers (binary protocol on tcp) where i can monitor the traffic, performance, crashes etc. Not necessarily as detailed as new relic. How do people in general monitor thrift on production. Its not just about if the server is up or not, i am talking more about all the other metrics like response time, throughput, crashes etc.